# What could be the problem with my SLD style?

Tags: geoserver

I am editing an SLD style from the cookbook. I ahve a polygon layer, that I want to style according to the attribute (Name of the block). I want each block to have a different color. So I used the PropertyIsEqualTo rule but its giving me this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of ID and the layer is: ECB:reds
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Please help.. ECB is a workspace and the layer name is reds... the attribute value that I am using is Name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Attribute-based polygon</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Attribute-based polygon</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>ID</Name>
          <Title>Nored</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>NORED</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#F5A9F2</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Cenored</Name>
          <Title>Cenored</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>CENORED</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#F3F781</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
         <Rule>
          <Name>ErongoRed</Name>
          <Title>ErongoRed</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ERONGORED</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
         <Rule>
          <Name>SouthernRed</Name>
          <Title>SouthernRed</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>SOUTHERNRED</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#F6CEF5</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>CentralRed</Name>
          <Title>CentralRed</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ID</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>CENTRALRED</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#819FF7</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

thats my sld.. sorry the attribute field is id.

Comment: Could you include the SLD code?

Comment: I cant post it its saying its too long... am quite new here can I perhaps send it to you then you help me?

Comment: You could try using a paste-and-share tool (e.g. https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: Set the NamedLayer Name element to the name of your layer - ECB:Red

Comment: do you have an attribute called ID in your dataset? note this is case sensetive?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where your SLD is being used - GeoServer? QGIS?

This is what I use on a polygon layer from PostGIS in GeoServer.  The layer is **topographicarea**, the field is **descriptive_group** and the attribute value is **building**.  The layer is filtered by field and attribute and then a style is applied to each classification.

```
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>topographicarea</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>topographicarea</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Building</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Abstract>Building</se:Abstract>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>descriptive_group</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Building</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffcc99</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>General Surface</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Abstract>General Surface - Manmade</se:Abstract>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>descriptive_group</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>General Surface</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>make</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>Manmade</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cccc99</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
```

And so on through all the different features.

Comment: My SLD is used in geoserver dear.. Thank you I will go through this quickly... and again where do I click to post my sld code so u see it?

Comment: You could edit your orginal post and just copy and paste the first few rules in your SLD, then style them with the  preformatted code button {}.

Answer (score 1):

What Editor are you using. SLD are not meant to be edited directly in text editors. Instead use uDIG or QGIS to style your layer then export the Style in SLD format and thenimport it in Geoserver. This way you will be much faster and accurate. [Atlas Styler](http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler) is specifically made to style data.

Comment: I am using Notepad++.. I tried that..its working but when I add the labels on then they are not showing in geoserver...

Comment: Labels should show up. uDIG allows to see the sld file inside program and make changes. I suggest you open the layer in uDIG and experiment there.

Comment: I dont have uDIG and am quite not familiar to it....

Comment: Get it here. http://udig.refractions.net/. Its just another gis. It is easy.